# Add event listener in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to add an event listener to my WordPress site, but somehow it doesn't work and I have no idea why... I am a new developer with just a little self education, so a simple explanation on what's not working there would be appreciated!

Here is my code and what I'm trying to do: I got 6 equal column with 16.66% width, and I want to change their width when clicking on them, so the clicked column become 50% and the rest 10%:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callIt);
function callIt() {     
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('col-1-6');
    for (var j=0; j < x.lenght; j++) {
        x[j].addEventListener = ("click", function(){miniPage(this.Id);});
    }
}
var activeTab;
function miniPage(activeTab) {
    var i, arz;
    arz = document.getElementsByClassName('col-1-6');
    for (i = 0; i < arz.length; i++) {
        arz[i].style.width = "10%";
    }
document.getElementById(activeTab).style.width = "50%";

}
```

Comment: We can't see where the variable `activeTab` is assigned. Note, it should be the `id` as `String`, not element `node`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have some typos.

- On line 4, you need to change `lenght` to `length`.
- On line 5, the `=` shouldn't be there. You need to instead call `addEventListener` as a "method" of the `x[j]`, like so:
  `x[j].addEventListener("click", /* here goes your handler */)`
- On line 5, you need to change `this.Id` to `this.id` if you want to access `id` attribute of the corresponding DOM element.

Also, you don't need to declare the `activeTab` variable on line 8, since it's used as a function argument on the next line. Basically (omitting the explanation about `arguments` Array), when you declare a function, the value of the arguments you write in the parentheses `()` will be taken from the place you call the function.
For example, in your case the value of the `activeTab` will be assigned on line 5, when you call `miniPage` function as a `click` handler.

I don't see the HTML in your question, so let's assume it has a `table` with `thead` and `th`, for simplicity. This also, of course, can be done with other HTML DOM elements like `div`, but with additional styles.

**Please note** that in order to make your JS work, you'll need some `id` attributes assigned to the DOM elements in your HTML. I've done it in the example below.

You can see working example down below. In your JS, I changed only the things I mentioned above.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callIt);
function callIt() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('col-1-6');
    for (var j=0; j < x.length; j++) {
        x[j].addEventListener("click", function(){miniPage(this.id);});
    }
}

function miniPage(activeTab) {
    var i, arz;
    arz = document.getElementsByClassName('col-1-6');
    for (i = 0; i < arz.length; i++) {
        arz[i].style.width = "10%";
    }
    document.getElementById(activeTab).style.width = "50%";
}
```

```css
.col-1-6 {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 16.66%;
  height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <th class="col-1-6" id="first-column">
    1st column
  </th>
  <th class="col-1-6" id="second-column">
    2nd column
  </th>
  <th class="col-1-6" id="third-column">
    3rd column
  </th>
  <th class="col-1-6" id="fourth-column">
    4th column
  </th>
  <th class="col-1-6" id="fifth-column">
    5th column
  </th>
  <th class="col-1-6" id="sixth-column">
    6th column
  </th>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: thx alot man, i have been searching for a whole week to figure it out! God bless you! ;)

Comment: @amir, if this answer solved your problem you can accept it as the correct answer by clicking the green tickbox. Congrats to you both, very good question and answer!